# Navigation hooks not fired when navigating back from a child route IONIC 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have an Ionic app in which I have to navigate from my `/tabs/cart` page to `/address` page.
then after doing some actions in the address page, I am navigating to the cart page `/tabs/cart` the navigation is working fine, but the problem i that the navigation hooks (ionViewDidEnter) do not fire, I tried to find a solution online but nothing worked.

```
this.router.navigate(['/address'], {
        queryParams: {}
      });

this.router.navigate(['/tabs/cart'], {
      queryParams: {
        flow: "fromAddressPage"
      }
    });
```

following is the router for both app and tabs module

```
 { path: 'address', loadChildren: './address/address.module#AddressPageModule' }


{
        path: 'cart',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../cart/cart.module').then(m => m.CartPageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
```

Comment: try using ionViewWillEnter which fires before a page become active.

Comment: its not working, none of the navigation hooks are getting fired.

Comment: as per this - https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15260 , hooks are triggered only if you are switching between Pages, they will not triggered with Tabs switch.